# How to create an array and push for object properties?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a situation where I have values from the backend `dataItem`. Now I want to push these values to an array and set for object properties, so next step would be map object properties to he form fields. With below code I got the values and assign it to object `selectedOwners` and its working good, but problem is everytime user `addProcessOwner` is creating new object for every user and when `$scope.processDTO.prcsOwner = selectedOwners.fullName;` do this its only assigning last value to the form field.

Once user select multiple owners how can I display all owners into form field?

main.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control  customReadOnly"
            id="prcsOwner" required ng-model="processDTO.prcsOwner"
            ng-click="openPrcsOwner()" ng-disabled="PROCESS_EDIT"/>
```

ctrl.js

```
var selectedOwners = {};
$scope.selectedOwnerGrid = rcsaAssessmentService.selectedProcessOwners();
$scope.addProcessOwner = function(dataItem) {
    selectedOwners = {
        fullName: dataItem.fullName,
        workerKey: dataItem.workerKey
    }
    console.log('WORKER DATA', selectedOwners);
}
$scope.selectedProcessOwner = function() {
    $scope.prcsOwnerModal.close();
    $scope.processDTO.processOwnerWorkerKey = selectedOwners.workerKey;
    $scope.processDTO.prcsOwner = selectedOwners.fullName;
    console.log('FORM DATA', $scope.processDTO.processOwnerWorkerKey, $scope.processDTO.prcsOwner);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you trying to do is this:

`var selectedOwners = [];`

...

```
var selectedOwner = {
    fullName: dataItem.fullName,
    workerKey: dataItem.workerKey
}

selectedOwners.push(selectedOwner);
```

Comment: How i will assign all selected owners like `$scope.processDTO.prcsOwner = selectedOwners.fullName;`

Comment: Do you want to assign to the form to send to the backend? In this case you can send your data (`selectedOwners`), using `$http.post`.

Comment: First i wanted it to display all selected owners to the user in the field then once user fill all required fields then i will send it to backend.